# Import CSV with memo fields into Microsoft Access tables

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, csv, export

Let me first say, that I am not a programmer, so I am not familiar with Visual Basic for Access (VBA). I understand queries and macros to a point where I can automate database transactions that can get me from point A t B.

I am looking to take a CSV file saved from Microsoft Excel and import them into Microsoft Access 2003 on a daily basis. The CSV file is a daily feed I receive from another company.

What can a non-programmer do inside Microsoft Access to import this data once a day?

My biggest issue is with memo fields. It seems many of the simple ways of importing data like linking tables truncates memo fields into the first 255 characters. I need to bring all the data.

Any tips, suggestions, or tested procedures would be helpful.

Comment: In Access, if you set the data type of a field to ***Text*** then you are limited to 255 characters.  You would have to set the data type to ***Memo*** if you need to store more than 255 characters.  Actually to import CSV files will create problems for you.  You are better off importing a tab delimited text file instead.  VBA is the best and easiest way to get the job done.

Comment: Assuming the table is already created with the correct data types, the import of the data still truncates to 255 characters for memo fields.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839785) might give you what you need.

Comment: Your link just confirms linking to an Excel worksheet in Access, truncates any memo fields to the first 255 characters. That doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this code below.  Paste this into a module and make the necessary changes to fit your needs.  Design a table with the fields you need and their type and reference it below.  Create a form with a command button that will run an event procedure.  Call the module you created.

```
Public Sub ImportTextFile()
' to use the ADODB.Recordset, be sure you have a reference set to ADO
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strFile As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim varSplit As Variant
Dim intCount As Integer


  Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
' CHANGE THE TABLE NAME HERE
rst.Open "TblNameHere", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
' CHANGE THE TEXT FILE NAME AND LOCATION HERE
strFile = "C:\Desktop\fullextract.txt"

Open strFile For Input As #1

Dim i As Integer

Do Until EOF(1)
   ' This counter is just to get to the applicable line before importing
   intCount = intCount + 1
   ' reads the text file line by line
   Line Input #1, strInput
   ' starts importing on the second line.  Change the number to match which line you
   ' want to start importing from
   If intCount >= 2 Then
       ' creates a single dimension array using the split function
       varSplit = Split(strInput, ",", , vbTextCompare)
       ' adds the record
       With rst
           .AddNew
       ' change the range 0 To 254 to fit your needs. I was importing 254 fields.
            For i = 0 To 254
                .Fields(i) = varSplit(i)
           Next i
           .Update
       End With

   End If
Loop
' garbage collection
Close #1
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```